# Liferay 6.1.1 CE GA2 domain's root redirects according session

Tags: session, redirect, liferay, root

I've a strange feature in my environment. When I 1st arrive to my domain's root url it redirects me correctly /home. But if I click any sub pages and try to go to domain's root it redirects me back to the page where I left. When I delete the cookies everything works accordingly till I click any links.

Any ideas where to find some pointers for this mysterious issue?

Yours
Heikki

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution.

Portal settings had wrong hosts and this was its weird reflection.